# How can I precompile assets using Travis CI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, travis-ci

In the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) they have an example on how to precompile assets with Capistrano. It is as simple as adding `load 'deploy/assets'` to the Capfile. I simply want to achieve the same effect, precompiling assets, while using Travis CI instead. This is what I've done so far:

script/travis.sh:

```
run "bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
```

.travis.yml:

```
 before_install:
  - chmod +x script/travis.sh
 script: script/travis.sh
 language: ruby
 rvm:
 - 2.2
 deploy:
   provider: heroku
```

When this is built on Travis it fails and I get this from the log:

```
$ script/travis.sh
script/travis.sh: line 1: run: command not found
The command "script/travis.sh" exited with 127.
```

I also want to add that my shell script knowledge is very limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but I'm leaning towards the `run` command not being available in the travis shell, as against Capistrano. I'd say you should probably just leave your travis.sh as:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

And try again. Let me know the results of that

Comment: After switching to your suggestion the build pass, but I get this:

`# HEAD detached at 0a16f9c
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

# modified:   public/assets/.sprockets-manifest-2e58c9853eed847b777ae1ce5e9b3103.json
# modified:   script/travis.sh`

and some untracked files.

Comment: yeah, I believe that's because the compiled assets are not automatically tracked. Simply adding `git commit -m #whatever commit message` to your travis.sh should resolve these new issues.

Comment: hey missed one step: `git add public/assets`, then `git commit -m` above

Comment: Thank you sir! Greatly appreciated.